# Why are fn:matches and fn:replace throwing parse errors in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to use these two string functions (`matches` and `replace`) in my XSLT stylesheet. But at runtime I get below error for `matches` and a similar error for `replace`:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Parse Error in matches function.
oracle.xdo11g.xpath.XPathException: Parse Error in matches function.
    at oracle.xdo11g.xslt.XSLProcessor.reportException(XSLProcessor.java:965)
    at oracle.xdo11g.xslt.XSLProcessor.newXSLStylesheet(XSLProcessor.java:725)
    at oracle.xdo11g.parser.v2.XSLProcessor.newXSLStylesheet(XSLProcessor.java:391)
```

The xslt processor version is 2.0, which should support these functions as per http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_systemproperty.asp.

I also tried to replicate the simple examples listed on w3org (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) and still same issue.

Strangely, the string functions `contains` and `translate` work just fine.

Here is my simple XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="matches('abracadabra', 'bra')"/> <!-- gives error-->
    <xsl:value-of select="replace('abracadabra', 'bra', '*')"/><!-- gives error-->
    <xsl:value-of select="translate('abracadabra','ab','34')"/><!-- works fine-->
    <xsl:value-of select="contains('abracadabra', 'bra')"/><!-- works fine-->
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Irrespective of my XML input these should work.
Can anyone suggest what is wrong here and how this can be fixed?

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 2.0 with Java then you can use Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/, it has XSLT and XPath 2.0 support since they were standardized.

Comment: `translate()` and `contains()` are XSLT 1.0 (or more precisely, XPath 1.0) functions. So, obviously, you are still performing this transformation with an XLST 1.0 processor, even if you think otherwise.

Comment: That does makes sense that I might still be on XSLT 1.0, but then why <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" /> return the version as 2? (xsl:version - The version of XSLT implemented by the processor)

Comment: Oracle arguably [jumped the gun](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28991413/290085) in returning an `xsl:version` of 2 before implementing all of XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Oracle's XML Developer's Kit (12c Release 1)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/toc.htm) only partially supports XSLT 2.0.   Unfortunately, `fn:matches` and `fn:replace` are [**not supported**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_ref_standards.htm#BABGDJHF):

> Some features of these specifications are not supported in the current
>   release:
>
> - The Schema Import and Static Typing features are not supported, but    the XML Schema built-in types specified by the XPath 2.0 Datamodel
>     are supported.
> - The schema-element and schema-attribute nodetests are not supported.
> - The XSLT instruction xsl:number uses XSLT 1.0 semantics and syntax.
> - The use-when standard attribute is not supported.
> - The processor does not honor the attribute of required on xsl:param.
> - Tunnel parameters are not supported.
> - Regular expression instructions are not supported in XSLT.
> - **The XPath 2.0 functions fn:tokenize, fn:matches, and fn:replace are    not supported.**
> - format-dateTime, format-date, and format-time functions are not    supported.
> - The content model for xsl:attribute, xsl:comment, xsl:message and the    way to compute key values of xsl:key and xsl:sort are still 1.0
>     behavior.
> - attribute [xsl:]inherit-namespaces for xsl:copy, xsl:element, and    literal result elements is not supported.

Whether this sort of partial support justifies returning `2.0` from

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />
```

is an interesting question.

Comment: In the WG we've occasionally had interesting discussions on what non-conformant processors should return from system-property(), which can go on surprisingly long before someone points out that if the processor is non-conformant, it's unlikely to take much notice of what the spec says.